# how to change id per form in select2 django formset

Tags: javascript, html, django, jquery-select2

i need to increment id field forms per form

default id which django provides is `id_formsetname_set-0-fieldName` and 0 increment one by one

in my case named `id_items_set-0-model` and for second form will be `id_items_set-1-model` it display in inspect element source code from browser , i used this for loo script

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    $("#id_items_set-"+i+"-model").select2();
 }
```

but only worked for the first form , i dont want to use django-select2

my template looks like this

this is my snippet

```html
<tbody class="tbody tb1 " id="form_set">
                    
                    {% for item in items.forms %}
                    <tr class="p-0 col-12">                    
                 <td class="">
                  <div class="col-12 p-0 mt-3 inp">
                {{item.price | add_class:'col-12 '}}
                
             </div>
             </td>
                
            <td class="">
            <div class="col-12 p-0 mt-3 inp">    
                 {{item.quantity | add_class:'col-12 '}}
            </div>
           </td>
            <td class="">
               <div class="col-12 p-0 mt-3 inp">
                {{item.model | add_class:'col-12 0model model' | attr:'id:id_items_set-0-model'}}
                                
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
                
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.tb1 tr:last').formset({
            prefix:'{{items.prefix}}',
            addText:'add',
            deleteText:'remove',
            addCssClass:'btn btn-success',
        });
    })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                 $("#id_items_set-"+i+"-model").select2();
  }            
 })
</script>
```

only work for my first form then doesnt have any effect on other forms ? is there something i did wrongly in the script part please?

Answer (score 1):

`jquery.formset` has `added` attribute we can call a function every time when a row created

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.tb1 tr:last').formset({
        prefix:'{{items.prefix}}',
        addText:'add',
        deleteText:'remove',
        addCssClass:'btn btn-success',
        added:function($row){
                  $('.model').select2()
              }
      });
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked on django .
Could you try this please .
and if you could share with us a link for real example in case this doesn't work

```
 $(()=>{
     let ids = document.querySelectorAll("[id=*'id_items_set']");
     ids.forEach((element)=>{
    $(element).select2();
    });
     });
```

Comment: it says (Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[id=*'id_items_set']' is not a valid selector.

Comment: what it means $(()=> ? !

Comment: its a real example , i have shared

Comment: This means that there is no element that contain this part of id .

Comment: Try settimeout(  function(){let ids = document.querySelectorAll("[id=*'id_items_set']"); ids.forEach((element)=>{ $(element).select2(); });},3000); if it works that mean that ur trying to call element even before exisiting in the dom

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[id=*'id_items_set']' is not a valid selector. still doesnt work

Comment: This means that you sre not creating element with the wanted ids

Comment: but it display the id name in the inspect element

Comment: thanks alot , i have a new way , jquery.formset let you to call a function every time a new row added